Differential operations on tensors and scalars
Example №1:
$\nabla\times(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})=
\\
=\vec{e}_{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}_{i}}\times(a_{j}\vec{e}_{j}\times b_{k}\vec{e}_{k})=\vec{e}_{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}_{i}}\times(a_{j}b_{k}e_{pjk}\vec{e}_{p})=e_{pjk}\dfrac{\partial a_{j}b_{k}}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{i}\times\vec{e}_{p}=
\\
=e_{pjk}e_{qip}\dfrac{\partial a_{j}b_{k}}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{q}=
\\
=\delta_{jq}\delta_{ki}\dfrac{\partial a_{j}b_{k}}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{q}-\delta_{ji}\delta_{kq}\dfrac{\partial a_{j}b_{k}}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{q}=
\\
=\dfrac{\partial a_{j}b_{i}}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{j}-\dfrac{\partial a_{i}b_{q}}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{q}=
\\
=(\dfrac{\partial a_{j}}{\partial{x}_{i}}b_{i}+\dfrac{\partial b_{i}}{\partial{x}_{i}}a_{j})\vec{e}_{j}-(\dfrac{\partial a_{i}}{\partial{x}_{i}}b_{j}+\dfrac{\partial b_{j}}{\partial{x}_{i}}a_{i})\vec{e}_{j}=
\\
=(\vec{b}\nabla)\vec{a}+\vec{a}(\nabla\vec{b})-\vec{b}(\nabla\vec{a})-(\vec{a}\nabla)\vec{b}$.
Example №2:
$\nabla\times(\phi\cdot\hat{T})=
\\
=\vec{e}_{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}_{i}}\times(\phi T_{jk}\vec{e}_{j}\otimes\vec{e}_k)=
\\
=\dfrac{\partial(\phi T_{jk})}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{i}\times\vec{e}_{j}\otimes\vec{e}_k=
\\
=\dfrac{\partial(\phi T_{jk})}{\partial{x}_{i}}e_{pij}\vec{e}_{p}\otimes\vec{e}_k=
\\
=e_{pij}T_{jk}\dfrac{\partial(\phi)}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{p}\otimes\vec{e}_k+e_{pij}\phi\dfrac{\partial(T_{jk})}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{p}\otimes\vec{e}_k=
\\
=(\nabla\phi)\times\hat{T}+\phi(\nabla\times\hat{T})$.
Using index notation, transform the expression if $\vec{c}$ is a constant vector, $\vec{r}$ is a radius vector, $r$ is the modulus of a radius vector: $\nabla\times(\phi(r)(\vec{c}\times\vec{r}))$.
My solution:
$\nabla\times(\phi(r)(\vec{c}\times\vec{r}))=
\\
=\vec{e}_{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}_{i}}\phi(r)\times(c_{j}\vec{e}_{j}\times r_{k}\vec{e}_{k})=
\\
=\vec{e}_{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}_{i}}\phi(r)\times(c_{j}r_{k}e_{pjk}\vec{e}_{p})=
\\
=e_{pjk}\dfrac{\partial(c_{j}r_{k}\phi(r))}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{i}\times\vec{e}_{p}=
\\
=e_{pjk}e_{qip}\dfrac{\partial(c_{j}r_{k}\phi(r))}{\partial{x}_{i}}\phi(r)\vec{e}_{q}=
\\
=\delta_{jq}\delta_{ki}\dfrac{\partial(c_{j}r_{k}\phi(r))}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{q}-\delta_{ji}\delta_{kq}\dfrac{\partial(c_{j}r_{k}\phi(r))}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{q}=
\\
=\dfrac{\partial(c_{j}r_{i}\phi(r))}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{j}-\dfrac{\partial(c_{i}r_{q}\phi(r))}{\partial{x}_{i}}\vec{e}_{q}=
\\
=(\dfrac{\partial(c_{j}r_{i})}{\partial{x}_{i}}\phi(r)+\dfrac{\partial(\phi(r))}{\partial{x}_{i}}c_{j}r_{i})\vec{e}_{j}-(\dfrac{\partial(c_{i}r_{j})}{\partial{x}_{i}}\phi(r)+\dfrac{\partial(\phi(r))}{\partial{x}_{i}}c_{i}r_{j})\vec{e}_{j}=
\\
=(\dfrac{\partial(c_{j})}{\partial{x}_{i}}r_{i}\phi(r)+\dfrac{\partial(r_{i})}{\partial{x}_{i}}c_{j}\phi(r)+\dfrac{\partial(\phi(r))}{\partial{x}_{i}}c_{j}r_{i})\vec{e}_{j}-
\\
-(\dfrac{\partial(c_{i})}{\partial{x}_{i}}r_{j}\phi(r)+\dfrac{\partial(r_{j})}{\partial{x}_{i}}c_{i}\phi(r)+\dfrac{\partial(\phi(r))}{\partial{x}_{i}}c_{i}r_{j})\vec{e}_{j}=
\\
=(\vec{r}\nabla)\vec{c}\phi(r)+\vec{c}(\nabla\vec{r})\phi(r)-\vec{r}(\nabla\vec{c})\phi(r)-(\vec{c}\nabla)\vec{r}\phi(r)=
\\
=(\vec{r}\nabla)\vec{c}\phi(r)+\vec{c}(\nabla\vec{r})\phi(r)-(\vec{c}\nabla)\vec{r}\phi(r)$.
I believe there is an error in my solution. Since his answer is the same as in example № 1, only multiplied by $\phi(r)$ as a constant. Please tell me what I need to fix to get the right solution?

You actually missed some terms in the penultimate line. The result should be
$$\boldsymbol\nabla\times[\phi(r)[\mathbf c\times\mathbf r]]=\phi\, (\mathbf r\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla)\,\mathbf c+\phi\, \mathbf c \,(\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot\mathbf r)+\mathbf c\,(\mathbf r\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla)\phi\\
\hspace{4cm}-\phi\,\mathbf r\,(\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot\mathbf c)-\phi\,(\mathbf c\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla)\,\mathbf r-\mathbf r\,(\mathbf c\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla)\phi$$
Moreover, be careful with the operator $(\mathbf a\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla)$ because it acts on what's to its right, so if you have for instance $(\mathbf a\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla)\mathbf c\,\phi$ it might be misinterpreted as it acting on $\mathbf c\cdot\phi$ instead of just $\mathbf c$. To fix this you should rather write $\phi(\mathbf a\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla)\mathbf c$ or $(\mathbf a\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla)[\mathbf c]\,\phi$
